# Progressively add strings from array to html element using timeout

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a string to a html element every `500ms` using a `for` loop to pass the string to a function which updates the target element.

I'm not sure if i'm approaching this the right way or if it's possible as it just displays the strings all at once rather than every `500ms`.

The desired effect is the strings displays as if someone is typing.

The code is below and here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/NORSE/vochxa3f/).

```
var content = "Hello, Universe!";
var split = content.split("");
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('place-here');

for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    addChar(split[i]);
}

function addChar(char) {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  var timer = setTimeout(function() {
    target[0].innerHTML += char;
  }, 500);  
}
```

Comment: All of your timeouts are being set at the same starting time. With no gaps in between, they all fire concurrently (more or less) 500ms after you set them.

Comment: `timer` variable is undefined always in that context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a proposal without `setTimeout`, but with `setInterval` and some other changes.

```js
var content = "Hello, Universe!",
    target = document.getElementById('ticker'),
    i = 0,
    timer = setInterval(addChar, 500);

function addChar() {
    if (i < content.length) {
        target.innerHTML += content[i];
        i++;
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="ticker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all timeout functions starts at the same time (in 500ms). You can compute different timeouts by multiplying interval with the index of char in array:

```
for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    addChar(split[i], i);
}
function addChar(char, i) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        target[0].innerHTML += char;
    }, 500 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix setInterval and shift to do this :

```
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('place-here');

function display(element, string, timer) {

  var split = string.split("");

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    element.innerHTML += split.shift()

    if (split.length == 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, timer)
}

display(target[0], "Hello, Universe!", 500)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made you a working javascript code that you can paste in your fiddle. Your problem was that you call the setTimetout all at the same time so after 500 milliseconds everything executes instead of waiting on the other one to finish

```
var content = "Hello, Universe!";
var split = content.split("");
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('place-here');

console.log(split);
addChar(0);


function addChar(i) {
    var currentChar = split[i];
  console.log(i);
  console.log(currentChar);
    setTimeout(function() {
    if(typeof currentChar !== 'undefined'){
        target[0].innerHTML += currentChar; 
        addChar(i+1);
    }
  }, 1000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `setInterval()` :

here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vochxa3f/9/)

code here :

```js
var content = "Hello, Universe!";
var split = content.split("");
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('place-here');


var length = split.length;
var count = 0;

var timer = setInterval(function() {
   addChar(split[count]);
    count++;
    if(count>=length) clearInterval(timer);
}, 500); 



function addChar(char) {
 target[0].innerHTML += char;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="place-here">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes in your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vochxa3f/10/

```
var content = "Hello, Universe!";
var split = content.split("");
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('place-here');

function addChar(str, i) {
  if(i < str.length) {
        target[0].innerHTML += str[i];
        setTimeout(addChar, 500, str, ++i); 
  }
}
setTimeout(addChar(content, 0), 500);
```

The addChar function call itself with setTimeout() incrementing the variable i so in the next time it'll get another character from content.

Note that setTimeout() first argument is the reference to the function, in this case only "addChar" without "()". The arguments for the function stars at 3rd parameter and forth.